# Can windows 7 installed in virtual box suppot 3d graphics for gaming

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, virtualbox, games

I have recently installed Windows 7 in my virtual box and my main OS is ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  I have gallium 0.4 on AMD RS-780.  Can I get a stepwise manual to install graphic card accelerators required to enable high quality gaming in virtual box?
This is the status of my computer.
[image]

Comment: See also http://www.maketecheasier.com/enable-3d-acceleration-in-virtualbox/ . If you have a problem, consider asking on the VBox forums as well.

Comment: it shows the procedure to install drivers for intel mother board

Comment: the second link how to install drivers using ubuntu but i should do it using windows 7

Comment: "In the general settings pane, check the check box titled, 'Enable 3D acceleration'. That’s it. The virtual machine has been enabled for 3D accelerated graphics now." What part of that involved installing anything?

Comment: yes i have 3d acceleration enabled in my virtual machine and i have posted the screenshot of entire description of my virtual machine

Comment: The screenshot you posted lacks sufficient information to give you advice. If you enabled 3d acceleration as in the link I gave you, and it is not working, your next step is to identify your graphics card and file a bug report against virtualbox. It is likely your bug report will be sent "upstream" to vbox, so you can save time by filing with vbox directly.